# Django Compressor, S3 and SASS, compiled files not uploaded

Tags: python, django, amazon-s3, django-compressor

I'm trying to setup Django Compressor with Amazon s3 and SASS, but I run into this problem.

So, these are the settings for django compressor:

```
########## STATIC FILE CONFIGURATION
# See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#static-root
STATIC_ROOT = normpath(join(SITE_ROOT, 'static'))

# See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#static-url
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#std:setting-STATICFILES_DIRS
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    normpath(join(SITE_ROOT, 'assets')),
)
COMPRESS_CSS_FILTERS = [
    #creates absolute urls from relative ones
    'compressor.filters.css_default.CssAbsoluteFilter',
    #css minimizer
    'compressor.filters.cssmin.CSSMinFilter'
]
COMPRESS_OUTPUT_DIR = '' #fixes bug with absolute urls
COMPRESS_PRECOMPILERS = (
    ('text/x-scss', 'sass --scss --compass {infile} {outfile}'),
    ('text/x-sass', 'sass --compass {infile} {outfile}'),
)
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'devfest.storage.CachedS3BotoStorage'
STATICFILES_STORAGE = DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = get_env_setting('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID')
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = get_env_setting('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY')
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = 'asd'

COMPRESS_OFFLINE = True
COMPRESS_ENABLED = True
COMPRESS_URL = 'https://{}.s3.amazonaws.com/'.format(AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME)
COMPRESS_ROOT = STATIC_ROOT
```

This is the part of the template where the files are called

```
{% compress css %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/normalize.css' %}">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/x-sass" href="{% static 'css/main.sass' %}">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/font-awesome.min.css' %}">
{% endcompress css %}
```

The problem is that the compressed files are not uploaded, since they are put in a dedicated folder (only files in assets are uploaded)

```
» tree static/                                                                                                                                                                                
static/
├── css
│   └── 46086ae5ebb4.css
└── manifest.json
```

Did I do something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed this way:

```
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto.S3BotoStorage'
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'devfest.storage.CachedS3BotoStorage'
COMPRESS_STORAGE = STATICFILES_STORAGE

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = get_env_setting('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID')
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = get_env_setting('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY')
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = 'asd'
AWS_QUERYSTRING_AUTH = False

COMPRESS_OFFLINE = True
COMPRESS_URL = 'https://{}.s3.amazonaws.com/'.format(AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME)
COMPRESS_ROOT = STATIC_ROOT
```

I added AWS_QUERYSTRING_AUTH = False because it was creating a different url for each page reload.

Comment: What does the CachedS3BotoStorage do? And how did this fix it?

Comment: I can't remember where I get the CachedS3BotoStorage, but I think it was from here http://jeanphix.me/2012/02/08/django-heroku-compressor-storages/ :)